# TypeLoadException: Collectible type '{0}' may not have Thread or Context static members

Tags: c#

I am facing a weird exception: Google cannot find anything about it (which is quite rare).

The code:

```
new Query<TElement>(/* ... arguments ...*/);
```

Thew an exception

> **System.TypeLoadException**
>
> Collectible type 'L.Caching.Query`1[<>transientClass1]' may not have Thread or Context static members.

I finally solved that issue, but this worth telling a bit google about it! (I will answer this question)

Let me put things in their context:

- I am calling the "new" that threw the exception from a runtime compiled lambda.
- The class taking place of TElement, e.g. `<>transientClass1`, is a dynamically generated class (using Reflection.Emit) - quite inofensive: it is the equivalent of what generates the compiler when writing an anonymous type `new{a=thing, b=otherThing}`
- This "anonmyous" class works well in many other parts of my application (dont think about wrong IL emission)
- `Query<T>` is just another generic class.

What could cause that exception ?

Comment: FWIW, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx) points out this restriction at the end. Incidentally, this was the very first result when searching Google with your exception message after removing the type name specific to your project.

Comment: Thanks, I did googled without my type, of course. But nobody speaks about this exception in perticular (and I already knew about these restrictions): try to google "may not have Thread or Context static members." and you wont find this string. See my answer for details about what it seemed weird to me.

Comment: I googled ["Collectible type may not have Thread or Context static members."](https://www.google.com/search?q=Collectible+type++may+not+have+Thread+or+Context+static+members.) and the referenced page was the first result. Your solution does seem to be in line with it.

Comment: Yep. But no reference about this exception (and transientClass1<> has no thread static field, and Query<T> worked well elsewere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is partly in the last section of ['Collectible Assemblies for Dynamic Type Generation'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx)

> **Thread-static data** Thread-static variables are not supported.

But this part is not sufficent, since the class `<>transientClass1` does not declare any thread static data.

BUT `Query<T>` does. Thus, because `<>transientClass1`is in a collectible assembly, `Query< <>transientClass1>` must fit the same requirements (since it will be collectible as well).

That is why `Query<T>` may be used elsewere sucessfully, `<>transientClass1` as well, but mixing both threw this exception.

To solve this issue, I just had to move my thread static field in another class (and use safely in `Query<T>`).